# Migrate this question back to Video Production

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked this question some time ago in AVP:

https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23213/how-to-record-quality-dialogues-with-dslr

The question is about technical challenge when producing a movie, so it belongs here. Not to Sound, even if it concerns setup of microphones.

On a side note, the migration could have been handled better. Well, today I was looking for it, and it just disappeared. Without notice, it was moved to Sound. Must admit, that was frustrating, because it was moved without any notification whatsoever.

Comment: I have had a look at that question, and there is nothing in it that I would class as specific to Video. You are asking a microphone choice question.

Comment: @DrMayhem - I think the argument is that it is an audio question that is solely for the purposes of video.  I don't think we have a solid idea of how we want to handle this kind of thing at the moment since audio is a critical portion of video.  The split makes sense since Video isn't a critical part of audio, but it seems like at least some audio questions will need to be here.  I'm just not sure how we figure out where that dividing line is.

Answer (score 4):

We did our best to notify everyone that this was going to happen, I'm sorry that you found the experience jilting. We featured a few meta posts, and I ran notifications on the system notice bar for a week while it was ongoing, but that only notified people that happened to visit the site during that time.

In the future, we'll consider running some queries to identify users that have contributed more than a bit, but don't historically hit the site every week. That'll be a little difficult, but we might be able to do something. That is, of course, if this ever needs to be done again - this was something we hadn't really done before.

In any event, I'm glad you found it, and sorry for the startle.

Answer (score 3):

While a lot of effort went into trying to make sure the migrations went smoothly, some errors are inevitable with anything this large, particularly on questions that straddle both areas.  When you see questions that were migrated in error, flag them as requiring moderator attention and mention that they should be moved back.

Notifications also did pop up for any migrated posts when they were migrated.  It would have appeared in the general notification spot for updates on SE.  If you didn't get a notification, then something wasn't working correctly.